# html special chars in tag onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I have a tag with onclick event, like that:

```
onclick="cl_showEvents({ 
    'posts' :     
    [{
        'CategoryName':'categoryName',
        'postID':'1',
        'title':'title',
        'address':'address',
        'time':'00:00'}]
    })"
```

It works fine, until an escape sequence is issued, like so:

```
onclick="cl_showEvents({ 
    'posts' :     
    [{
        'CategoryName':'categoryName',
        'postID':'1',
        'title':'title',
        'address':'streetName st&#39;',
        'time':'00:00'}]
    })"
```

What do I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a backslash before the ampersand:

```
 'address':'streetName st\&#39;'
```

to avoid the converting of the entity `&39;` into the char it represents.

Comment: No, the backslash doesn't keep the entity from being converted into an apostrophe. It escapes the apostrophe that the entity is converted into.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to your question - I'm not sure how `&#39;` breaks this construction - but this is way too much stuff to put in a tag IMO. I would recommend moving the whole thing into a separate script in the bottom of the page or in a `load`/ `DOMLoad` event.

Sans jQuery:

```
document.getElementById("your_element").onclick = function() 
  {
   cl_showEvents({ 
   'posts' :     
    [{
    'CategoryName':'categoryName',
    'postID':'1',
    'title':'title',
    'address':'streetName st&#39;',
    'time':'00:00'}]
    })

  }
```

Comment: I know that and I will, but I've got interested with that issue

Comment: This is what FireBug sais: missing } after property list. I tried to google it, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

It's not because the character is HTML encoded, it's just because it's an apostrophe. As you are using apostrophes as string delimiters, you have to escape the apostrophe inside the string:

```
onclick="cl_showEvents({ 
  'posts' :     
  [{
    'CategoryName':'categoryName',
    'postID':'1',
    'title':'title',
    'address':'streetName st\&#39;',
    'time':'00:00'}]
  })"
```

Note that the apostrophe doesn't need to be HTML encoded, you can just use a regular apostrophe (and seeing the code like this makes it more obvious why the apostrophe needs escaping):

```
onclick="cl_showEvents({ 
  'posts' :     
  [{
    'CategoryName':'categoryName',
    'postID':'1',
    'title':'title',
    'address':'streetName st\'',
    'time':'00:00'}]
  })"
```